# Autousing pytest fixtures defined in a separate module

Tags: python, fixtures, pytest

I have the following file tree in my project:

```
...
tests/
    __init__.py
    test_abc.py
...
```

I have a fixture defined in `__init__.py`:

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def client():
    return TestClient()
```

I want to use this fixture in `test_abc.py`:

```
from . import client

def test_def():
    client.get(...) # Throws an error
```

How can I use my `autouse` fixture in my test methods from another modules without passing an explicit reference to the fixture, or using a pytest decorator?

Comment: You should put the fixture into a `conftest` file: http://pytest.org/latest/plugins.html?highlight=hooks#conftest-py-local-per-directory-plugins

Comment: I don't want to put it there...is it the only way for the fixtures to resolve?

Comment: The other way is to write a plugin: http://pytest.org/latest/plugins.html?highlight=hooks#writing-a-plugin-by-looking-at-examples

Comment: I've tried moving the fixtures to a `conftest.py`, but still `NameError: global name 'client' is not defined`.

Comment: Declare a parameter in your test method with the name of the fixture: `def test_def(client):`.

Comment: That's exactly the reason why I want to use `autouse=True`, so that I won't have to declare the argument for each test.

Comment: OK, now I see what you are trying to accomplish. Autouse is meant for fixtures which do some setup required by all tests, and may or may not return something still useful as a fixture to be used by tests. Tests which want to access what is returned by the fixture *have* to declare the fixture as a parameter, so they can access it. So if your tests want to access the fixture, they have to declare it as a parameter, that's how pytest works. Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. Thank you very much for clarifying! You can submit an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Autouse is meant for fixtures which do some setup required by all tests, and may or may not return something still useful as a fixture to be used by tests.

Tests which want to access what is returned by the fixture have to declare the fixture as a parameter, so they can access it. So if your tests want to access the fixture, they have to declare it as a parameter, that's how pytest works. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to put your fixture into the `conftest.py` file and set the scope to something like `@pytest.fixture(scope="module")` so that it's invoked once per test module.

From the pytest docs on [sharing fixtures across classes, modules, packages or session](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/fixtures.html#scope-sharing-fixtures-across-classes-modules-packages-or-session), it says:

`"The next example puts the fixture function into a separate conftest.py file so that tests from multiple test modules in the directory can access the fixture function"`

```
# content of conftest.py
import pytest
import smtplib


@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def smtp_connection():
    return smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587, timeout=5)
```

```
# content of test_module.py


def test_ehlo(smtp_connection):
    response, msg = smtp_connection.ehlo()
    assert response == 250
    assert b"smtp.gmail.com" in msg
    assert 0  # for demo purposes


def test_noop(smtp_connection):
    response, msg = smtp_connection.noop()
    assert response == 250
    assert 0  # for demo purposes
```